# How can i query the amount of reversed and overlapping UVs in maya

Tags: python, maya, mel

I am currently developing a tool for artists on maya to make sure their meshes are clean before export.
One thing i'd like to check for is if there are any overlapping or reversed UV on their meshes. I know maya display this information the UV editor (see screen cap below), but i was wondering if there's any way for me to query this value by script (i'm using python).

[UV editor displaying the overlapping and reversed UV count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQ7TO.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the polyUVSet command.